# Name and age code with validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

I am stuck on a piece of code using while loops.

```
Namecorrect = ""
Name = input("Please enter your name: ")
while Namecorrect == "":
    NameCorrect = input("Your name is" ,Name, "is that correct? ")
if Namecorrect == "yes":
    Agecorrect = ""
    Age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    while Agecorrect == "":
        Agecorrect = input("Your age is" ,Age, "is that correct? ")
    if Agecorrect == "yes":
        print("Please come in")
    else:
        print ("Please retry")
else:
    print("Please retry")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you need to do? What's wrong with the existing code?

Comment: I get the error message:

Comment: NameCorrect = input("Your name is" ,Name, "is that correct? ")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: @ZombieGamer I'm assuming you want to concatenate those strings together. `input("Your name is" + Name + "is that correct? ")` or  `input(f"Your name is {Name} is that correct?")` with python 3.6

Comment: Alright... `input()` takes one argument. You’re giving it three separate arguments. You’ll have to concatenate the three strings into a single string. *EDIT* JSextonn beat me to it.

Comment: it also just repeats the question "your name is (name) is that correct" no matter what answer you give it                                                           (Please enter your name: bob
Your name is bob is that correct? no
Your name is bob is that correct? yes
Your name is bob is that correct?) etc

Comment: Side note: change your variables names to [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: it also just repeats the question "your name is

You have Indention Error and **ask** without a Condition.
Consider the following:

```
Namecorrect = None
Agecorrect = None

while True:
    if Namecorrect != 'yes':
        Name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        NameCorrect = input("Your name is {}, is that correct? ".format(Name))

    if Namecorrect == 'yes':
        Age = input("Please enter your age: ")
        Agecorrect = input("Your age is {}, is that correct? ".format(Age))

        if Agecorrect == "yes":
            print("Please come in")
            break

    print("Please retry")
```